# Open PDF in Samsung s4 Mobile Browser

Tags: android, asp.net, pdf

I am trying to show pdf in samsung s4 mobile browser but it is downloading instead.

Here is my code

```
response.Clear();
response.Buffer = true;
response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
response.OutputStream.Write(output.ToArray(), 0, output.ToArray().Length);
response.OutputStream.Flush();
response.OutputStream.Close();
output.Close();
```

In desktop browser it is working fine, `output` i am getting correctly.

Is there any way to show pdf in Samsung s4 Mobile?